# OpenVPN public IP on tun0 interface instead of vpn network

Tags: openvpn

I can't access devices in local network behind openvpn client using public IP of VPN server.

A little bit of information:

Openvpn server (openVZ, Debian7)

Opevpn client (raspberry pi 2 raspbian jessie).

Everythink works fine, when I use other vpn client to access local network behind other client (client 1 VPN <> server VPN <> client 2 VPN). 
From client 2 I have access to local network behind client 1 VPN.
In server cfg I set iroute etc.

Problem is when I try access for example ip camera in local network behind client 1 using public IP of VPN server.

On the client side set:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -p tcp -d 192.168.2.2 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.2:8080
```

On the server set:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i venet0 -p tcp -d 10.8.0.6 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i venet0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.6:8080
```

10.8.0.6 is the raspberry pi 2 ip address in VPN

I used tcpdump to see why it won't work.

The reason is that the packets from VPN server have a public IP in source address.
When vpn client recived this packet with public ip source address, automatically respond using WAN interface not tun0.

Someone can help me? What should I do set in iptables on server?

PS: In firewall on server I have only one iptables rule:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source PUBLICIP
```